# Is there any react native library that I can use to achieve these two parameters in the UI below?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

[image]

In the image above, I would like to know which library I can use to achieve the stories on the first screen and also, which library can I use to switch between the **Current News, World News, and Politics**. Also is there a way to put the status progress bar on the third screen? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

to achieve the news tabs, you can use `react-native-tab-view`, it is highly customizable and highly reliable, the second screen is what we call the *Two Layered UI* and can be easily achieved by using the `react-native-panhandler`. The third screen is an example of the `react-native-pager-view`. There are lot of examples of these libraries as well as extensive documentations, All the best!